# How do I query json subobjects and return the whole parent?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I don't want to write loops.. I want to see the all the choices available (using LINQ, SelectTokens, JSON.NET or any other some tools) that lets me return a/an array object relative to something inside.For example:

```
{
    "theFamilies": [{
        "parent1": "Joe",
        "parent2": "Mary",
        "child1": "Andy"
    }, {
        "parent1": "Bob",
        "parent2": "Mary",
        "child1": "Mark"
    }]
}
```

Return a list of the entire object(s) that contain `"parent2" = "Mary"`.

What if.. the nesting were deeper?  Is there a nice way of avoid/ignoring nesting depth and recursively get all that satisfy the condition that does not require any coding change?

Any comments regarding the benefits or detriments of each solution would be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for [Json.NET SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm)

In your case:

```
var o = JObject.Parse("{'theFamilies': [{'parent1': 'Joe','parent2': 'Mary','child1': 'Andy'}, {'parent1': 'Bob','parent2': 'Mary','child1': 'Mark'}]}");
var res = o.SelectToken("theFamilies[0].parent2");
```

**UPD**
for all tokens you should use [SelectTokens](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm)

```
var res = o.SelectTokens("theFamilies[*].parent2");
```

Comment: I don't think that this actually returns a list of objects where "parent2" = "Mary".

Comment: @nas yep, just one token

Answer (score -2):

your data seems to be an array of `Family` objects. You can create a poco for this and use `LINQ` to select those matching after deserializing the json to C# type. Something like following can be used -

```
        var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Families>("json");

        var match = t.theFamilies.Where(a => a.parent2 == "Mary").ToList();

        public class Families
        {
            public List<Family> theFamilies { get; set; }

        }

        public class Family
        {
            public string parent1 { get; set; }
            public string parent2 { get; set; }
            public string child1 { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: _"What if.. the nesting were deeper? Is there a nice way of avoid/ignoring nesting depth and recursively get all that satisfy the condition that does not require any coding change?"_

Comment: _"What if.. the nesting were deeper"_ - in which way?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not the OP. Your answer however doesn't answer that question.

Comment: What if I don't want to create any classes, but simply manipulate JSON?